# PostgreSQL: Which connectivity uses psql tool of PostgreSQL

Tags: jdbc, odbc, postgresql, database-connectivity

Does anybody know how psql accesses PostgreSQL database? What it uses odbc, jdbc or some native database library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html).

Comment: Thanks, are you developer or it is written somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: @Tim If you click on a poster's name you can see his profile.

Comment: @Peter: Don't misunderstand me, I do not offend anybody, just want to see official information by myself. Btw, it is written "PHP programmer; SVN and PostgreSQL administrator", I am not sure if every PostgreSQL administrator knows such details.

Comment: Comment on my 1st comment: by developer I meant developer of psql, not developer in general as it may seem..

Comment: That's right, Makefile of psql shows that: psql: $(OBJS) $(libpq_builddir)/libpq.a

Comment: No, I'm not related to the PGDG (PostgreSQL Global Development Group) in any way though I'm satisfied "customer" and enthusiast. And I have built Postgres from source quite a few times.